# ASP.net MVC 4 - Castle Windsor - Method not found: 'System.Web.Http.Services.DependencyResolver

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor

I am getting the below error in ASP.net MVC 4 RC with Castle Windsor. This happens when I am using WebApi (APIController). The same is working fine 
in my local machines (hosted in IIS), but not in the hosted environment.

Method not found: 'System.Web.Http.Services.DependencyResolver

I followed the below article for the Castle Windsor Integration.
http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectionInASPNETWebAPIWithCastleWindsor.aspx

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

I am getting the same error when I deploy the default asp.net mvc4 internet application. Following lines throws the error. This works fine in the build machine and almost all other machines, but not in the hosting environment.

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: I believe dependency injection is done differently in MVC4 vs Web Api. Which is it? Can you please post some code?

Comment: I am getting this same error when I deploy the default ASP.net MVC4 Internet application. This time no CastleWindsor or dependency injection. The line that throws the error is             config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: I would make sure that your host environment has the latest System.Web assemblies that include the WebAPI parts.

Answer (score 0):

Your host doesn't have the right packages.

1. Uninstall
2. Reinstall.

Look at [Move to Web API RC, Get: Method not found: 'System.Web.Http.Services.DependencyResolver System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_ServiceResolver()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994619/move-to-web-api-rc-get-method-not-found-system-web-http-services-dependencyr)